# How to display a value if there is a value in the column and empty if there is nothing?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get the value of one column if it exists and leave it empty if there is no value in that column

```
Table 1 (Student):
 id  Name  dateofbirth
  1   John   16-09-2015
  2   Mark   25-08-2016
  3   Matt   20-08-2017
  4   Peter  16-08-2014

 Table 2 (Relationship):

  id StudentID NextOfKin Relationship  Active
  1     1        David        Mother        Y
  2     2        Frank        Father        N
  3     3        Jacob        Mother        Y
  4     3        Park         Mother        N


 SELECT a.Name, a.dateofbirth, b.NextOfKin
 FROM dbo.Student a
 LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Relationship b
     ON a.id = b.StudentID
 WHERE b.Relationship = 'Mother'
   AND b.Active = 'Y'
```

I want to do something like if b.NextOfKin has a value enter it, else leave it blank. Please can you advice

In the above case, Peter does not have a nextOf kin, and Mark does not have a mother. I still want his name to appear but if no mother it should be blank

Comment: There is no empty values in your example

Comment: what is your current output and what is your expected output

Comment: I'm not one to judge, but David and Jacob are unconventional names for mothers :P

Comment: @HoneyBadger this is VARCHAR type, then this is non binary.

Comment: Tip of today: Chose table aliases that make sense! Like s for Student and r for Relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `coalesce()` function and put all other conditions in `ON Clause` instead of `Where Clause`

```
SELECT a.Name, a.dateofbirth, coalesce(b.NextOfKin,'') as NextOfKin
 FROM dbo.Student a
 LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Relationship b
 ON a.id = b.StudentID
 and b.Relationship = 'Mother'
 AND b.Active = 'Y'
```

Comment: @fab06, its still giving me 3 records. do you think its because of the relationship ='Mother'

Comment: @edcoder, have you tried my current edited answer ? It should show all the rows of first table

Comment: Thank You so much @fab06. Worked perfectly